# How to know when to use fit_generator() in keras when training data gets too big for fit()?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, keras

When using keras for machine learning, `model.fit()` is used when training data is small. When training data is too big, `model.fit_generator()` is recommended instead of `model.fit()`. How does one know when data size has become too large?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The moment you run into memory errors when trying to take the training data into memory, you'll have to switch to `fit_generator()`. There is extra overhead associated with generating data on the fly (and reading from disk to do so), so training a model on a dataset that lives in memory will always be faster.